# How to display .asmx page on UIWebview?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, ios5, ios6

I am not able to display `asmx` page in `UIWebView`.
If there is any other way please tell.

Answer (score 1):

`UIWebView` cannot display .asmx file

These are the file formats suppoorted by `UIWebView`

```
Excel (.xls)

Keynote (.key.zip)

Numbers (.numbers.zip)

Pages (.pages.zip)

PDF (.pdf)

Powerpoint (.ppt)

Word (.doc)
Rich Text Format (.rtf)

Rich Text Format Directory (.rtfd.zip)

Keynote '09 (.key)

Numbers '09 (.numbers)

Pages '09 (.pages)
```